# Error when listing issues GitHub REST API

Tags: node.js, rest, github-api

The GitHub API Documentation lists the following paths to obtain a list of issues relevant to the authenticated user:

```
GET /issues

GET /user/issues
```

However, when attempting to use either of these, I am given the following error message:

```
{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#list-issues"
}
```

I am not sure why this is happening. I have tried accessing these paths through my browser and via the following code:

```
    let url = "https://api.github.com/issues";
    let response = await(fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
    }));

    let json = await(response.json());

    console.log("GetIssuesCreated: [" + JSON.stringify(json, null, 2) + "]");

    return json;
```

Any help regarding why this would happen would be wonderful and greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a reason as to why this isn't working, but I have found that the GitHub Search API seems to be what I should have used all along.

It is possible this part of the API could have been discontinued.

For anyone else, the query I ended up using was

```
https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=author:USERNAME
```